# Insert text using php on webserver

Tags: php, html

I make some web only using html, php. This web is simple.

Input some text using below php code.

```
$log_file_name = 'mylog.html'; // Change to the log file name
$message1 = $_POST['message1']."<BR>"; // incoming message
$message2 = $_POST['message2']."<BR>"; // incoming message
$message3 = $_POST['message3']."<BR>"; // incoming message
file_put_contents($log_file_name, $message1, FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents($log_file_name, $message2, FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents($log_file_name, $message3, FILE_APPEND);
```

mylog.html has below text.

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
```

I want change mylog.html like a below

```
AAAA'$message1'
BBBB'$message2'
CCCC'$message3'
```

Comment: Read the manual: http://php.net/language.types.string .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First read in the old contents of the file, append your new messages to each line, and write that out.

```
$log_file_name = 'mylog.html'; // Change to the log file name
$message1 = "'" . $_POST['message1']."'<BR>"; // incoming message
$message2 = "'" . $_POST['message2']."'<BR>"; // incoming message
$message3 = "'" . $_POST['message3']."'<BR>"; // incoming message
$old = file_get_contents($log_file_name);
$lines = explode('<BR>', $old);
$lines[0] .= $message1;
$lines[1] .= $message2;
$lines[2] .= $message3;
unset($lines[3]); // Get rid of extra <BR>
file_put_contents($log_file_name, implode('', $lines));
```

If you have lots of POST messages, it would probably be better to make them an array. The form should use:

```
<input type="text" name="message[]">
```

for all the message inputs. Then you can use a `foreach` loop to process them.

```
$log_file_name = 'mylog.html'; // Change to the log file name
$old = file_get_contents($log_file_name);
$lines = explode('<BR>', $old);
foreach ($_POST['message'] as $i => $message) {
    $lines[$i] .= "'$message'<BR>";
}
unset($lines[count[$lines]-1); // Get rid of extra <BR>
file_put_contents($log_file_name, implode('', $lines));
```

Comment: Thank you. that script works. If mylog.html has too many line & POST message, how can use that.

I try using FOR but didn't work. :(

If you have time plz help me

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to process them in a loop

Comment: Thank you. you are genius.
I have some qustion <input type="text" name="message[]">  <----message has no number?

Comment: html change like this but not work.
<form action="save-to-log.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="message[]">
<input type="text" name="message[]">
<input type="text" name="message[]">
<input type="submit" value="SAVE" /></form>

Comment: I was wrong. that is work.
thank you very much.
god bless you

Comment: Hello.I have one more question. I input some text using script in mylog.html. And I input text again in 'mylog.html'. I want replace text but this script just append text. I can change text only simple file using str_ireplace. So If you have time plz help me.

Comment: After you read it from the file, it's just a string. You can do whatever you want to it before writing it back out.

Comment: mylog.html has message box so I write first text in box. And php script overwrite mylog.html. When I reopen mylog.html that file change. I erase message box data in mylog.html. message box  has first text and second text appended.
first. read mylog.html input data and overwrite mylog.html 
second. read mylog.html and I modify input data and overwrite mylog.html

Comment: I think you should really rethink what you're doing. Instead of modifying an HTML file in place, put your user input in a database. And instead of an HTML file, use a script that displays the data from the database.

Comment: Thank you. your advise but now I can,t install db. so I made script not using db. plz check below.
<?php
foreach (glob("EVENT-*.html") as $filename) {
    $log_file_name = "$filename";
}
$old = file_get_contents($log_file_name);
$lines = explode('<textarea name="message[]"></textarea>', $old);
$blank = test;
foreach ($_POST['message'] as $i => $message) {
    $lines[$i] .= "$message";
    if ($lines = "";){
        file_put_contents($log_file_name, implode('', $blank));
    }else{
        file_put_contents($log_file_name, implode('', $lines));
    }
}
header( "Location:$log_file_name" )
?>

Comment: 1. $message is null replace "test".
2. $message has some text -> change <textarea name="message[]">$message</textarea>

Comment: Don't try to put code in comments. Add it as an UPDATE at the end of your question.